# JQueryUI Tabs with shadows

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, shadow

Stackers, I need to put shadows around my tabs previously created using [JQueryUI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) plugin. Shadows must be on the right and top of tabs.

Using moz-box-shadow or similar could be great, but my application should be view on IE too.

My JQuery code (very simple):

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

This is how it looks:
[image: Tabs]

Anybody know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a class to these tabs?

Comment: @Kyle Sure, I can add them if we need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PIE.htc css3 shadows do work in internet explorer 6+ : http://css3pie.com/ (demo available)

The PIE shadows look better than the IE shadow/dropshadow filters.

Comment: Something like this is what I need. Thanks Willem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using CSS3 for real browsers and a filter for IE:

Add a class to your tab `tab-shadow` and use this CSS:

```
.tab-shadow
{
    box-shadow:2px -2px 6px #333333; /*standard CSS3*/
    -moz-box-shadow:2px -2px 6px #333333; /*firefox*/
    -webkit-box-shadow:2px -2px 6px #333333; /*webkit (safari, chrome*/
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=2, Direction=310, Color=’#000000′); /*ie*/
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px dashed #f00;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Not that it will only work in IE with a border set (from personal experience.)

[This should be what you're after](http://jsfiddle.net/Wa2pE/1/) :)

Comment: You solution works well. I vote up this answer but @Willem's answer is more what I need. Really appreciate your help Kyle. Good job :)